# How to open Steam via terminal?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

Is there any terminal command to open Steam on Ubuntu 14.04 ? And if so, is there any command to open it's games, for example DOTA2?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For launching games on Steam via command line, Steam used a URI-scheme for installing or launching games. You need to find out the 'appid' (application ID) for the game you are trying to launch (for example DOTA2 is 570) and execute a `steam steam://run/`[appid] command. (for example, using DOTA2, `steam steam://run/570`)

Comment: Thats great but how do i find the appid

Comment: See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149837/how-do-i-find-the-id-for-a-game-on-steam

Answer (score 0):

`steam` is the command that will let you launch Steam from terminal. It's man page suggests there are no documented command line options (aka flags, like `-abcd`)

Personally have no idea how to launch games through command line, as my Steam on Linux is currently empty (don't game as much as used to), but will provide edit later once i find out

**Edit**

Apparently Steam stores games in `$HOME/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/` directory. For instance, I've downloaded game called Capre Diem, which is in python, and uses a shell script to launch the actual game. To lauch it through terminal , I had to run

```
bash .steam/steam/steamapps/common/Carpe\ Diem/Carpe\ Diem.sh
```

Because some games may be in variety of languages, my opinion is that there's no conclusive, singular way to run games from terminal. Rather, it takes looking around the directories in `.steam/steam/steamapps/common/` for each respective game.

Comment: Okay I am looking forward to it, meantime I'll try to find solution myself and post it here

Comment: Edit posted, please review

Comment: It appears that steam has its own way to launch games. (see answer above)